# Can a returning US citizen elect not to use the automated passport kiosks?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen. Every time I use the automated passport kiosks, regardless of the airport or who I'm travelling with, they *always* give me an X. This means I get to stand in yet another line and get all-but-waved-through when I eventually get to the officer.

In the interest of not having to stand in the first line for the kiosks, am I allowed to just go to the visitors line instead? Or will I get sent back and told to use the kiosks? Or is there some other way to opt out of their use?

When I flew from Guangzhou to LAX in June, I stood in the kiosk line a full 45 minutes, only to receive an X and get sent to the visitors line for another 35 minutes. This is what I'm trying to avoid. Clearly it doesn't matter when flying into, say, BWI where there are no kiosks (and you're going to wait 2 hours for your luggage anyway), but rather for the airports that do have the kiosks. At LAX, *everyone* in the US citizen line was directed to kiosks.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78042/what-recourse-do-travelers-to-the-us-have-if-the-apc-kiosks-consistently-give-th

Comment: Can you? yes.  But then you will lose that "all-but-waved-through" speed when you get there, because the CBP officer will have to manually enter everything that you would have done at the kiosk (and probably sternly ask why you didn't use the kiosk like a good citizen).

Comment: On a slightly related note, you can do the same if you are a Schengen-member state citizen (i.e. skip the automatic Schengen gates -- they seem to always have a problem with my passport...).

Comment: You could also try [Mobile Passport](http://mobilepassport.us), however it's only supported in some airports. You could just avoid the kiosk line and go directly to the immigration officer. If you want, you can apply for a [redress number](http://trip.dhs.gov), which might help you if you're being confused with someone else.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to see if I can figure out why I'm getting denied at the kiosks when I next return to the US in December. I have a sneaking suspicion that my passport's biometrics are broken.

Comment: @tomasz That's a bit different because, under the Schengen Borders regulation, the other lanes are always “all passportd“ lanes, which EU citizens were explicitly allowed to choose even before automated kiosk started to appear (there is no such thing as a lane for Schengen-member-state citizens incidentally).

Comment: @Relaxed there are also EU/EEA/CH lanes for manual processing, aren't there?  The kiosks have requirements including minimum age and biometric passports that not everyone meets.

Comment: @phoog Yes usually, it might even be technically required, I am not sure anymore. I seem to recall flying into Schiphol and facing only “All passports” booths for something like 5 minutes before the Koninklijke Marechaussee got around opening another one for EU/EEA/CH citizens. What I meant by “other lanes“ is “other than EU/EEA/CH lanes“, whether automated or not. They have always been “all passports” or, in rare cases, “visa not required”, i.e. EU citizens were always explicitly allowed to use any lane they want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the Automated Passport Control kiosk rejects you, the reason for the rejection may be displayed on screen and/or printed on your X receipt as a "referral code." The code tells officers what the specific problem was.

A list of these codes is available in the [Automated Passport Control specifications](https://web.archive.org/web/20161227234750/https://help.cbp.gov/ci/fattach/get/94655/0/filename/APC+Automated+Passport+Control+ICD+-+Schema+2+0+v2.doc):

> Enforcement Referral
>   ER
>   Traveler has enforcement type issues
>
> Random Referral
>   RR
>   Traveler is selected for random compliance
>
> Declaration Referral
>   DR
>   Traveler answers Yes to any general declaration question
>
> APIS Problem
>   AP
>   Traveler is not found on a manifest
>
> Entry Authorization
>   EA
>   Visa Waiver traveler does not have an approved ESTA status
>
> Biometric Failure
>   BF
>   Traveler has no Enrollment Record on file or biometrics cannot be verified (applicable to Visa Waiver travelers).
>
> Check Documentation
>   CD
>   Referral based on
>
> - Foreign national traveler’s passport expiration date is less than 6 months
> - USC or US LPR traveler’s document query results in a mismatch or not “Issued” status
>
> Technical Referral
>   TR
>   Referral based on
>
> - Traveler has attempted use the kiosk during the configurable enforcement lockout
> - Biometric pre-verify check returned a fault response
> - The return code from a vetting query was other than normal completion
> - A cancellation command from the kiosk that the traveler processing has been terminated.
>
> Passage Granted
>   PG
>   Traveler receives Passage Granted

You can use the regular lines, but in the interest of saving your own time and possibly sanity, there are a couple of other things you can try:

- If [Mobile Passport Control](http://mobilepassport.us/) is available at your destination terminal, do passport control from your smartphone. Unfortunately it's not yet available at LAX.
- If APC kiosks continually reject you, the thing to do is to file with the [Traveler Redress Inquiry Program](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip). This program is designed to resolve issues with repeatedly being delayed entry or referred to secondary. You'll be assigned a redress control number which you can add to your airline bookings. If you decide to do this, keep your kiosk receipts as you will need to submit them.

Comment: The OP stated that "they always give me an X."
Looking at the above codes (love codes), the only one that could always show is "ER" (law enforcement).
For example, if a passenger was ever fingerprinted by the police, for any reason, this code will forever appear at customs, even with no criminal record.
The OP could look into a biometric pass.  It is a 'red tape' issue.

Comment: @DominicCerisano He could also always have goods to declare, or have gotten a completely different reason on each attempt. Whatever the reason, the referral codes may help to understand what happened on a specific entry.

Comment: My 2010 e-passport NEVER works at kiosks. I don't know whether I damaged the chip or something but it always kicks me out. Over the years I've become quite skilled at deciding whether to wait in the "normal" queue or wait in the "e-passport" queue plus the time taken to get "waved through" when my e-passport fails. It depends on factors like queue size, approximate queue speed, and how much I care that day. But I usually beat the people who were in front of me coming off the plane. :) It's a fun little game to play when you really have nothing better to do...

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is unlikely kiosks would mysteriously reject someone every time just by coincidence. These kiosks are there to streamline security, not to create further bottlenecks. As I said, the biometric or "speedpass" system might be able to filter out whatever is causing this because of its enhanced background check. If they have your fingerprints anyway, might as well go the full monty.

Comment: So you can't keep your kiosk receipts (per your bullet re the redress program.) When you get referred to secondary, they keep your customs declaration and have you give the kiosk receipt (which they stamp) to the customs officer. (Source: Just passed through immigration at Boston.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Hm, well that complicates matters. Did you at least take note of the code on it?

Comment: Yeah, "ER" for an "enforcement referral," whatever that means. Took over an hour to clear immigration even though I was the third person off the plane. Luckily my connecting flight was delayed....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yeah, definitely go straight to [TRIP](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip). By "enforcement" they generally mean _law_ enforcement. If you don't get redress for whatever it is, you can count on lengthy delays in immigration every time you enter the US.

Comment: I have received "ER" code the last time I visited. The agent simply asked for what business purpose I was travelling. When I asked if that is why I wasn't able to go through automatically, he said "it can be one reason". Should I assume there is some sort of law enforcement issue? If so, why did they not mention anything about that?

Comment: @apscience It can be many things, but I wouldn't worry unless it happens again. Then go to TRIP and file for redress.

Answer (score 14):

My wife is a US citizen; I'm not.  As a matter of solidarity, whenever and wherever we travel, we go through immigration together.  So I can say with certainty that as recently as last Christmas, entering at Boston (where they have a lovely set of automated kiosks), US citizens can queue up with the *hoi polloi* and have their passport looked at by a human.  No suggestion has ever been made (in my earshot) that she should not have done this.

Comment: Not sure of your citizenship / visa, but my wife who is not US citizen and has a visa enters via the kiosks with me when we come back.

Comment: @Tom I'm a UK citizen, but I also have a very early-issue RFID passport (which has never worked, and which the Home Office declines to replace for free) and I enter the US on a B1/B2 visa rather than ESTA.  In my case, it's just simpler to queue, and talk to a human being.

Comment: And how many hours have you both wasted in queues, because you refuse to pay for a new passport? Sure, it would be nice if they replaced it for free but there comes a point where the replacement fee is the lesser evil.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you are, of course, completely free to pay to replace your own broken passport should you find yourself in such a situation.  I am free not to do so, and I don't; not because I can't count wasted time, but because I think it would be wrong to do.  In any case, because I'm on a visa, my journey through US immigration would not be any faster with a working RFID (unless I also paid to sign up for Global Entry), and in the UK I qualify to join the (fast-moving) e-passport queue (which I do, then fail at the gate, and get fast-tracked to the head of the regular queue).

Comment: Yup.  We are both citizens but we were traveling with some of her relatives that aren't--we went through the foreigner line at the preclearance facility in Vancouver.  The only problem was they wanted a customs form from us that we didn't realize we needed as we were told it was only for non-citizens.  We ended up with them ignoring the lack.  (The declaration on it would have been $0 anyway.)

Comment: @MadHatter OK -- I'd not picked up that you wouldn't be able to use the kiosks even with a working passport.

Comment: @DavidRicherby not to worry, David - I don't think I'd given any clue that this was so, so I'm not sure how you could have known!  Also, I have today applied for a new passport, as the old one's over nine and a half years old - it really was one of the very first RFID passports, and I don't think they'd got all the bugs ironed out yet.

Comment: I just came through LAX a couple of weeks ago, and the lady who was checking everyone’s paperwork and directing them to the appropriate line was certainly offering US citizens traveling with non-US citizens the option of staying together on the non-US line. I don’t know if that would have still been OK without being part of a group though.

Comment: @KRyan That must be new, in December I (citizen) was able to enter with a non-citizen through the US only line.

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness It also may have just been that at the time, the US line was very crowded and the non-US line may well have been shorter, so I think they were trying to encourage using it.

Comment: @MadHatter your wife can take you to the US citizens queue.  I've done this repeatedly at several different airports, both with a foreign *girlfriend* (who *lived in a different country from me)* and with my foreign wife (with whom I live in the US). You can also take your US-citizen wife to the EU/EEA/CH passports queue in the Schengen area as long as the UK remains in the freedom-of-movement regime; this is explicit in the Schengen codes.

Comment: @phoog thank you, yes.  If you read the comments thread above you'll see the point has already been made, and at the time, replied to.

Comment: @MadHatter I saw a comment about kiosks.  I wanted to make the point about the non-automated US-citizen queues that are still in place in many airports, including JFK, the airport that I use most.  I never use the kiosks because they cannot process my wife.

Comment: @phoog ah, sorry, that is clearer, and I am grateful for the information.  Boston Logan, my normal airport, has no US citizen queues without automation, so far as I know, so it hasn't arisen.  But since they finished the build-out at Logan and streamed out all second-use ESTAs to their own queue, the visas-and-first-time-ESTAs queue has got so short that we routinely get through before our baggage is on the carousel.  I can see little point in optimising that stage of the process any further!

Comment: @MadHatter and baggage handling at JFK is so slow that getting through immigration quickly is really only helpful if you don't check bags.  If you do check bags, you're just trading time in one part of the hall for time in another.

Answer (score 6):

The kiosks are optional, though neither the signs nor employees tell you that.  I've used the non-US line tho I'm a US citizen.  No hassle from the CBP inspector, a couple of times a curious question as to why I used that line, once the standard " what is the purpose of your trip to the US?" because he hadn't noticed I had a US PP.
Bottom line, it's unusual but OK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are most definitely optional, it’s in the CBP internal site:

APC kiosks are only intended to facilitate processing entering the United States.  There is no requirement that you must use them.  If you do not wish to use them, you should inform the Airport Official or CBP Officer directing the lines or watching the kiosks and ask where you should go to be manually processed.  You can also ask to speak with a Supervisor if you are denied manual processing.

The problem is, many times it’s an “airport official” or in other words, a minimum wage employee that obviously isn’t aware of all the policies.

I refuse to, as I typically pay outrageous fees as part of my airline ticket, and I don’t want to spend $54 to do a federal employees job by using a machine.