# What recourse do travelers to the US have if the APC kiosks consistently give them an "X" receipt?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

In [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78040/returning-us-citizen-can-i-elect-not-to-used-the-automated-passport-kiosks) question, a US citizen is complaining about *always* getting an "X" receipt when using the APC kiosks. What recourse do people in a similar situation have to fix this problem?

Since APC kiosks are available to [both US and VWP citizens](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc), there might be different options for US and non-US citizens.

Comment: If someone is a frequent traveler AND they always get an X receipt, then they might want to look into the known traveler programs or redress options. X's can be random (every nth traveler), they can be due to travel patterns, due to old red flags in a person's records, perhaps the person's name.

Comment: And I just answered this in the other question!